# Custom post type slug conflicts with another post type

Tags: php, wordpress

this is driving me nuts.

I have two custom post types

```
register_post_type( 'products',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Products' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products'),
    )
);

register_post_type( 'markets',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Markets' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Market' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'markets'),
    )
);
```

and two templates (archive-products.php and archive-markets.php)

The `products` custom type works. The archive page displays correctly, but the single page doesn't display. If I remove the `register_post_type` for markets the single page for products works.

The `markets` type however has the url of `www.website.com/products/a-market-post` which is really weird as it's using the slug from the products post type.

Does anyone know what might be happening? I've refreshed the permalinks page 1000 times and that doesn't do anything.

Cheers!

Comment: what is your permalink structure?

Comment: Where have you placed the code above? Within a function firing on the init hook?

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli Month and name

Comment: @NathanDawson I've tried both just directly running functions.php on it's own, and also inside a function that fires on init

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the 'taxonomies'.
And you don't need the "rewrite" because your slug remains the same.

```
function manufacturers_posts() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Products', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Product', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add new', 'book' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add new product' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'יAdd new' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'Show all' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'Show' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No products found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Trash is empty' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Products'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'public'        => true,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'tags' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
    );

    register_post_type( 'manufacturers', $args );
}

function manufacturers_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'manufacturers_taxonomy',                    //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces).
        'manufacturers',                             //post type name
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Products',                       //Display name
            'query_var' => true,
            'has_archive' => 'manufacturers',
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'manufacturers-archive',   // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                'with_front' => false                // Don't display the category base before
            )
        )
    );
}

    add_action( 'init', 'manufacturers_taxonomy');
    add_action( 'init', 'manufacturers_posts' );
```